# Insert 2D array into 3D array in python

Tags: python, numpy

Lets say I make the following arrays:

```
>>> a = zeros((2,2,2))
>>> b = ones((2,2))
```

How can I insert b into the middle of a? So my resulting array will look like

```
array([[[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]]])
```

Comment: How does a 2x2x2 array end up with 12 elements? It should only have 8 elements. Where do you want to insert the array? How do you define "middle"?

Comment: please comment what you have tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.insert()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html):

```
a = np.insert(a, 1, b, axis=0)
```

Comment: ahh, i had tried this but didn't putthe axis = 0 at the end

Answer (score 0):

A way to show same as your result is using `tuple`.
code:

```
b = numpy.ones((2,2))
a = numpy.zeros((2, 2))
tpl = a,
tpl = b,
tpl = a,
```

So you can consider it as 3dArray and also you can use `for` loop to add multi array into it.Hope be helpfull.

Answer (score -1):

```
a=np.zeros((3,2,2))
b=np.ones((2,2))

a[1]=b*1
```

That will produce your output.